# Steup Minio behind Nginx reverse proxy and access via react

Tags: docker, nginx-reverse-proxy, minio

For a few days, I've been trying to get minio running in docker-compose behind Nginx as a reverse proxy. Unfortunately, the Minio documentation did not help much (https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/integrations/setup-nginx-proxy-with-minio.html). If I want to access minio via react, I get a 403 error on the GET Methode (OPTIONS Methode works with 204) and the message:

`<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message></Error>"`

However, ACCESS_KEY and SECRET_KEY from frontend in react match those from minio (check even via console output).
I have tried various configuration versions below, but it won't work.

Maybe someone here knows what I could try, where to find documentation, or how to get the whole thing running.

Setup:

- minio in docker-compose
- nginx via SWAG in docker-compose

minio-nginx-config-file:

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
listen [::]:443 ssl;

server_name minio.*;

ignore_invalid_headers off;

proxy_buffering off;
proxy_request_buffering off;

include /config/nginx/ssl.conf;

client_max_body_size 0;

location / {
    include /config/nginx/proxy.conf;
    include /config/nginx/resolver.conf;

    proxy_set_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
    
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    chunked_transfer_encoding off;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

    proxy_set_header Range $slice_range;

    proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;

    set $upstream_app minio;
    set $upstream_port 9000;
    set $upstream_proto http;
    proxy_pass $upstream_proto://$upstream_app:$upstream_port/;
```

}
}

proxy.conf from SWAG:

```
## Version 2023/02/09 - Changelog: https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-swag/commits

/master/root/defaults/nginx/proxy.conf.sample

# Timeout if the real server is dead
proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503;

# Proxy Connection Settings
proxy_buffers 32 4k;
proxy_connect_timeout 240;
proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;
proxy_headers_hash_max_size 1024;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_read_timeout 240;
proxy_redirect http:// $scheme://;
proxy_send_timeout 240;

# Proxy Cache and Cookie Settings
proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_session;
#proxy_cookie_path / "/; Secure"; # enable at your own risk, may break certain apps
proxy_no_cache $cookie_session;

# Proxy Header Settings
proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Early-Data $ssl_early_data;
# proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header Proxy "";
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Method $request_method;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Uri $request_uri;
proxy_set_header X-Original-Method $request_method;
proxy_set_header X-Original-URL $scheme://$http_host$request_uri;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
```

React minio client:

```
const mc = new minio.Client({
  endPoint: process.env.REACT_APP_MINIO_HOST,
  port: parseInt(process.env.REACT_APP_MINIO_PORT, 10),
  useSSL: true,
  accessKey: process.env.REACT_APP_MINIO_ACCESS_KEY,
  secretKey: process.env.REACT_APP_MINIO_SECRET_KEY,
});
```

Comment: read https://blog.min.io/minio-nginx-letsencrypt-certbot/

Comment: Thanks @RichardRublev for your comment. I have already read the blog entry and could not find any solution or contradictions to my configuration to forward requests on the minio api.